# Video format can't be played or converted

Tags: video, codec, conversion

My customer gave me a series of videos, recorded from CC Cam. The extension is .dad. I couldn't play them on any player. (Obviously changed the extension for testing) and I wasn't able to convert them into a more common video format. 
I've tried Miro, HandBrake, VLC and some other apps on Mac to convert them with no success. 
Can anyone help me how can I convert them into a more common format that can be played and used in production. 
I can give more info about the video format if anyone asks and tells me how to get that info :)

MediaInfo Text View Output:

```
General
Complete name : /Users/hadi/Public/20151105-175532.dad
Format : AVC
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec
File size : 227 MiB

Video
Format : AVC
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile : Main@L3
Format settings, CABAC : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP : M=1, N=50
Width : 704 pixels
Height : 576 pixels
Display aspect ratio : 1.222
Color space : YUV
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0
Bit depth : 8 bits
Scan type : Progressive
```

Comment: What does [Mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) say for the OBS captured file? Use View -> Text mode and paste the readout into your Q.

Comment: @Mulvya Added MediInfo output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)* command:

```
ffmpeg -i "20151105-175532.dad" -c:v copy "20151105-175532.mp4"
```

*get 32-bit static build.

Comment: Great! Worked like a charm. I had to use 64Bit Mac version of ffmpeg binaries. But I worked.